# Compressed file (packed EXE) in WIX/MSI package increase MSI size by twice

Tags: installation, compression, wix, windows-installer, deployment

I have simple WiX MSI installer script. This script generate package what deploy only one exe file. This file is Java application wrapped to exe file. Overall size of this exe is 10MB. Unfortunately when I get builded  MSI final size of MSI increased by twice - e.g. 20MB.

I tried to change 
attribute Media/CompressionLevel to none/high/low/mszip - but can get acceptable MSI size.

Please help - I need get uncompressed MSI with similar  to deployed exe size +/- 3-4 MB!

Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

Windows Installer natively only supports some pretty basic compression formats.  You might want to give InstallAware's [Setup Squeezer](http://www.installaware.com/setup-squeezer.htm) a try.

Comment: Just recently found bug:

<Icon Id="myfile.exe" SourceFile="myfile.exe" />


WIX put file twice: one instance in .cab file, second as icon for shortcut.

I think I need save icon as separate file!

Thank you All!